# Joining G+ Hangouts slows the mouse to a crawl

Tags: performance, mouse, google-plus

Using a dual-display setup on a quad-core, win 7 desktop computer, whenever I join a Google Plus hangout, my mouse slows considerably down. Problem persist even after closing all Chrome windows.

Problem is triggered *during* the start of the plus window. No other performance degradation observed, and my CPU utilization is level around ~7-8%.

Might be relevant: using a Logitech webcam.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening, or hacks to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with other apps when mouse trails are turned on. You may also want to try different versions of your video driver.